# How do i overlap second div above the first one, if i am using mask-image on the first one?

Tags: html, css, gradient, mask

This is how it looks

[image]

Css for the first div, here i am using mask-image but I don't want this to affect the below product div. What can be done to achieve it?

```
.home__image {
  width: 100%;/* height: 400px; */
  z-index: -1;
  margin-bottom: -450px;
  mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

Second div

```css
.product {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-height: 400px;
  background-color: white(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  z-index: -1;
}

.product>img {
  max-height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  object-fit: contain;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Comment: It will much easier if we can see this + code live. Can you create a codepen or something?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use margin for this. Using negative margin will affect the layout and other elements. Use position absolute. Put both div with position absolute in a parent div with position relative.
For masking you can use pseudo classes before and after.